# Criteria for Something to be Considered a Mental Disorder

Tags: psychiatry, definition

I know this will probably be closed for being broad, but I think it certainly has an answer.

What are the criteria for something to be considered a mental disorder?

**Does a disorder need to be observable physiologically? Or is behavior/perception that is far from the norm enough?**

Comment: Related: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/13300

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE.  What have you been reading on the subject?

Comment: Also related: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/9313

Answer (score 4):

This is not just a broad question, it also differs depending on the specific person holding a specific orientation working at a specific clinical/academic setting. For a DSM-V discussion, see "[What is a Mental/Psychiatric Disorder? From DSM-IV to DSM-V](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3101504/)" by Stein et al.